# Reading YAML properties file in spring boot via PropertySourceFactory using YamlMapFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, properties-file

I'm trying to read a YAML configuration file through the spring boot @PropertySource mechanism, using a factory that utilizes the provided YamlMapFactoryBean parser.

The factory's implementation is as follows:

```
public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {
    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource encodedResource) {
        YamlMapFactoryBean factory = new YamlMapFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(encodedResource.getResource());

        Map<String, Object> map = factory.getObject();

        return new MapPropertySource(encodedResource.getResource().getDescription(), map);
    }
}
```

The YAML configuration file (foo.yml) is:

```
yaml:
  name: foo
  aliases:
    - abc
    - xyz
```

The corresponding entity is:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "yaml")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:foo.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class YamlFooProperties {

    private String name;
    private List<String> aliases;

    // Getters and Setters...
}
```

And finally, my test class is:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class YamlFooPropertiesTest {

    @Autowired
    private YamlFooProperties yamlFooProperties;

    @Test
    public void whenFactoryProvidedThenYamlPropertiesInjected() {
        assertThat(yamlFooProperties.getName()).isEqualTo("foo");
        assertThat(yamlFooProperties.getAliases()).containsExactly("abc", "xyz");
    }
}
```

When debugging the factory, I see that the YAML file is parsed correctly and added to spring boot's `propertySourceNames` structure. However, when accessing it from the test in an Autowired fashion, all fields are null and the test therefore fails.

Comment: any news on this?

Comment: @RenéWinkler unfortunately no, I ended up refactoring the whole thing to a simpler configuration and lost a bit of flexibility :-(

Comment: for new visitors, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/73110842/13115701