# How to test ConfigurationProperties with JUnit?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, yaml

This is my first time working with Externalized Configuration and yaml.

I created a yaml where I use the class name as KEY, and the field name as VALUE

YAML:

```
project:
  test:
    service:
      computator:
        # exclude field from beeing randomly valorized
        population:
          exclude:
            InputClass: 'myDate'
            AnotherClass: 'myName'
```

ExcludePopulationProperties:

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "project")
public class ExcludePopulationProperties {

    private Test test;

    @Data
    public static class Test {
        private Service service;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Service {
        private Computator computator;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Computator {
        private Population population;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Population {
        private Map<String, String> exclude;
    }

}
```

Test with JUnit 5:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ExcludePopulationProperties.class })
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class YamlTest {

    @Autowired
    private ExcludePopulationProperties excludePopulationProperties;

    @Test
    void testExternalConfiguration() {
        Map<String, String> map = excludePopulationProperties.getTest().getService().getComputator().getPopulation().getExclude();
        assertNotNull(map);
    }
```

The problem is that I have a NullPointerException because test is null [image]

So I'm not sure what is wrong here, I was expecting that the map was correctly populated.

I also tried to add

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.config.location=classpath:application-_test.yaml" })
```

on the YamlTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With these little changes, now I'm able to test the properties from YAML file.

I improved the yaml a little bit:

```
# test placeholders
project:
  test:
    service:
      computator:
        # exclude field from beeing randomly valorized
        population:
          exclude:
            InputClass: 
               - 'myDate'
            AnotherClass: 
               - 'myName'
```

so now the ExcludePopulationProperties have a Map<String, List<String>> instead of Map<String, String>, in this way I will be able to exclude more than one field from the same class

## SOLUTION 1

```
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "project")
public class ExcludePopulationProperties {

    private Test test;

    @Data
    public static class Test {
        private Service service;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Service {
        private Computator computator;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Computator {
        private Population population;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Population {
        private Map<String, List<String>> exclude;
    }

}
```

YamlPropertySourceFactory is a class implemented by Baeldung in this guide:
[@PropertySource with YAML Files in Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource)

```
public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource) throws IOException {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(resource.getResource());

        Properties properties = factory.getObject();

        return new PropertiesPropertySource(resource.getResource().getFilename(), properties);
    }

}
```

Test Class :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = { ExcludePopulationProperties.class })
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application-_test.yaml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
class YamlTest {

    @Autowired
    private ExcludePopulationProperties excludePopulationProperties;

    @Test
    void testExternalConfiguration() {
        Map<String, List<String>> map = excludePopulationProperties.getTest().getService().getComputator().getPopulation().getExclude();
        assertNotNull(map);
    }

}
```

Please note that for Mockito you need to use both, SpringExtension and MockitoExtension:

```
@Extensions({
        @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class),
        @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
})
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = { ExcludePopulationProperties.class })
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application-_test.yaml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
class YamlTest {

}
```

## SOLUTION 2

In order to avoid writing the annotations on all test classes,
add the jackson [jackson-dataformat-yaml](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml) dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
  <version>${jackson-dataformat-yaml.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The configuration properties class will be:

```
@Data
public class ExcludePopulationProperties {

    private Project project;

    @Data
    public static class Project {
        private Test test;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Test {
        private Service service;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Service {
        private Computator computator;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Computator {
        private Population population;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Population {
        private Map<String, List<String>> exclude;
    }

}
```

somewhere write a method to read ExcludePopulationProperties using jackson YAMLMapper:

```
    public static ExcludePopulationProperties buildExcludePopulationProperties() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("./src/test/resources/" + "application-_test.yaml"));
        YAMLMapper mapper = new YAMLMapper();
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
        return mapper.readValue(inputStream, ExcludePopulationProperties.class);
    }
```

then, wherever you need, simply call the static method,
and the test class will be simplier (from my point of view) :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class YamlTest {

    @Test
    void testExternalConfiguration() throws IOException {
        Map<String, List<String>> map = MyTestUtils.buildExcludePopulationProperties().getProject().getTest().getService().getComputator().getPopulation().getExclude();
        assertNotNull(map);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ExcludePopulationProperties` class should not be annotated with `@Component`. Instead, you should have the annotation `@EnableConfigurationProperties(ExcludePopulationProperties.class)` on a configuration class in your project (the main application class will work).

Change your properties class to look like this (removing `@Component`):

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "project")
public class ExcludePopulationProperties {
   ...
}
```

Change your application class to enable the configuration properties:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ExcludePopulationProperties.class)
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And the `YamlTest` class to look like this (using `@SpringBootTest`):

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { DemoApplication.class })
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.config.location=classpath:application-test.yaml" })
class YamlTest {

    @Autowired
    private ExcludePopulationProperties excludePopulationProperties;

    @Test
    void testExternalConfiguration() {
        Map<String, String> map = excludePopulationProperties.getTest().getService().getComputator().getPopulation().getExclude();
        assertNotNull(map);
        assertEquals(map.get("InputClass"), "myDate");
        assertEquals(map.get("AnotherClass"), "myName");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! What about the Factory?