# Spring Boot (REST Service) Integration tests fail with a null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, mockito, integration-testing

I am writing integration tests for my REST API.

Below are the classes.

The tests are failing due to a null pointer exception.
When I set a debug breakpoint and inspect, I see that in the class `CategoryConfiguration`,
the line `this.categoryConfigurationProperties.getValuesFromProperties()` returns `null`.

How can I ensure that the
`CategoryConfigurationProperties`
is initialized properly in tests and loads the values from `application-category.yml` file.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    MyService myService;
    
    public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> createProduct(...) {
        myService.createProduct(...);
        ...
        return...;
    }
}
    

@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    @Autowired
    MyProductHelper myProductHelper;
    
    public Product createProduct(...) {
        Category category = myProductHelper.getCategory(...);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
    
    
@Component
public class MyProductHelper {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("productCategoryMap")
    private Map<Product, Category> productCategoryMap;
    
    public Category getCategory(...) {
        return productCategoryMap.get(...);
    }
}
    
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CategoryConfigurationProperties.class)
public class CategoryConfiguration {
    private final CategoryConfigurationProperties categoryConfigurationProperties;
    
    public CategoryConfiguration(CategoryConfigurationProperties categoryConfigurationProperties) {
        this.categoryConfigurationProperties = categoryConfigurationProperties;
    }
    
    @Bean(name = "productCategoryMap")
    public Map<Product, Category> productCategoryMap() {
        this.categoryConfigurationProperties.getValuesFromProperties();
        ...
        return ...;
    }
    ...
}
    
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-config")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class CategoryConfigurationProperties {
    Map<String,Map<String,List<String>>> valuesFromProperties;
}
    
    
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class,MockitoExtension.class})
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyApplication.class},webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CategoryConfiguration.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.config.location=classpath:application-category.yml,classpath:application.properties"})
class MyControllerIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    
    @MockBean
    CategoryConfiguration categoryConfiguration;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        ...
    }
    
    @Test
    void testCreateProduct() {
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(...);
        // assert
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your configuration properties file in the project structure? By default, it is named `application.properties` located under `src > main > resources` and also check the existence of properties starting with `my-config.xx` in your `application.properties` file

Comment: The `application.properties` is located under `src > main > resources`. The values get pulled correctly when I run the service. It is only when I run the Junits / Test classes, the values are not getting pulled.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the same issue on my project.

[How to test Externalized Configuration reading from yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73020838/how-to-test-externalized-configuration-reading-from-yaml/)

take a look, especially at the annotations used, you need to find the right combination.