# Programatically read values from a resource yaml

Tags: java, spring, yaml

I have a utility class that I want to modify, not replace. I would like to read a value from the resource.yaml, but I cannot do this in the traditional way.

```java
// @Component // does not work because @UtilityClass
@UtilityClass // lombok
public class UtilityClass {

    // does not work because static
    @Value(${path.to.resource})
    private static String TARGET_RESOURCE;

    // does not work because @UtilityClass
    @Value(${path.to.resource})
    public void setTarget(String target) {
        UtilityClass.TARGET_RESOURCE = target;
    }

}
```

Ofc, I could manually make this a utility class, that lets spring initiate one instance, but not another. Make it a component, or some other solution. I do not care in the least.

What I want to do, not only here, but other situations, is to programatically read from the resource yaml file on demand.

```java
@UtilityClass
public class UtilityClass {

    private static final String TARGET_RESOURCE = readFromFile("path.to.resource");

    private static String readFromFile(String path) {
        // ???
    }
```

Comment: what you need is @ConfigurationProperties provided by Spring Boot, https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

Comment: @Aleson I'm not so sure, I don't see how I'd get a static reference.

Comment: ah I see you can use it with the combination of `@PropertySource` annotation if thats what you needed https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.23/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

Comment: Maybe can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/73110842/13115701