# Spring boot read properties from yml file into subclasses

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I would like to read a yaml file and parse it.
Is it possible to use subclasses for this?

I have a yaml file:

```yaml
expressions:
  - expression:
      literal: hello
  - expression:
      function:
        name: add
        params:
          - expression:
              literal: 1
          - expression:
              literal: 2
```

Then I have some classes to represent this structure.
Most notably:

```java
public interface Expression {
  String evaluate();
}
```

```java
public class LiteralExpression {
  private final String literal;

  public LiteralExpression(String literal) {
    this.value = literal;
  }

  public String evaluate() {
    return literal;
  }
}
```

```java
public class FunctionExpression {
  private final String name;
  private final Expression[] params;

  public LiteralExpression(String name, Expression... params) {
    this.value = name;
    this.params = params;
  }

  public String evaluate() {
    return Functions.getFunction(name).apply(Stream.of(params)
        .map(Expression::evaluate)
        .toArray(String[]::new));
  }
}
```

To read out the yaml file, I have a config glass with a `@PropertySource` annotation.

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:expressions.yaml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ProfielConfig {
  private List<Expression> expressions;
}
```

```java
public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {
  @Override
  public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource) {
    YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
    factory.setResources(resource.getResource());
    Properties properties = factory.getObject();

    return new PropertiesPropertySource(
      Objects.requireNonNull(resource.getResource().getFilename()),
      Objects.requireNonNull(properties)
    );
  }
}
```

When I use this setup, the expression properties stay `null`. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73110842/13115701

Comment: Thanks Paul. But it's a different question. In my case it's about YAML being unable to deal with subclasses of `Expression`. I was wondering if it's possible at all or if I should abandon this idea and go for a different approach.